# Swagger API not rendering in order at GUI

Tags: java, scala, spring-mvc, swagger, spray

I have developed REST api using scala and spray. for documentation I am using Swagger API for listing all apis.

at home page. host:port/index.html , where all apis are listed, They are not coming in order,I am supposed to diplay version vise apis like version

1.0.0,

1.0.1,

2.0.0,

It seems they come randomly, I have also used position parameter in `@API` but seems not working, how would I provide proper ordering of apis.

Comment: Since you're using spring-mvc I'd be curious if you've tried using [springfox.io](http://springfox.io) to generate the documentation. If not, would love for you to try it and provide some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of paths has been removed in Swagger v2.0, see discussions below.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1050

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1151

Possible alternatives include:

- go back to swagger 1.2
- use of tags to better organize resources
- locally change swagger-core as suggested in issue 1151
- try to re-open the issue once more :)